# How can I implement retry logic in Python's try-except block when input is incorrect

Tags: python, conditional-statements, try-except, except, retry-logic

I want x = False after any correct input (0 <= x <= 1). Whenever I have a correct input, the code will keep running, even though it shouldn't.

```
x = True
while x == True:
    score = input("Enter Score: ")
    try:
        score = float(score)
        if score < 0.6 and score >= 0.0:
            print("F")
            x = False
        elif score >= 0.6 and score < 0.7:
            print("D")
            x = False
        elif score >= 0.7 and score < 0.8:
            print("C")
            x = False
        elif score >= 0.8 and score < 0.9:
            print("B")
            x = False
        elif score >= 0.9 and score <= 1.0:
            print("A")
            x = False
        else:
            print("Your number is too big or too small!")
    except:
        print("Please enter a number!")
```

Comment: Works for me. https://ideone.com/4jnRwB

Comment: `while not success:`?

Answer (score 0):

The only exception you are equipped to deal with here is the `ValueError` that `float` might raise. If a `ValueError` is raised, start the loop over. If the number is in range, exit the loop, *then* print the letter grade.

There's also no need for the `x` flag.

```
while True:
    score = input("Enter Score: ")
    try:
        score = float(score)
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter a number!"
        continue

    if 0.0 <= score <= 1.0:
        break

    print("Your number is too big or too small!")
       
if score < 0.6:
    print("F")
elif score < 0.7:
    print("D")
elif score < 0.8:
    print("C")
elif score < 0.9:
    print("B")
else:
    print("A")
```

Answer (score -1):

Try and Except are used to catch exceptions during runtime.

What you are really looking for is a simple way to see if the input is a number.

```
if not score.isnumeric():
    print("Enter a number!")
```

Comment: If for example `score` is `'0.1'`, then `score.isnumeric()` is False. To identify whether a string is valid for conversion to float, you could use a regex, but putting `try...except` around the call to `float(num)` is pretty reasonable.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @slothrop A try and except block should never be used as the basis for your procedural logic. Languages like Java force the user to do such a thing- it is always poor practice.

Comment: @TheVindowViper you can go ahead and propose a working solution that doesn't use `try...except`! (Regex is one avenue, as I say.) I'm actually not unsympathetic to your point of view about exceptions, but I also don't feel we can rule out solutions which are very much in keeping with the official documentation of the language (see for example https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions)